# Yii2 combine multiple models in a search model

Tags: php, search, yii, yii2

> Yii2.0.15 and search models

First of all, I do not want to use an active record, I actually wrote all my queries with `new Query()`.
I'm working on a store system which its users have different roles(`financial manager, representative, visitor, store, etc ...`), and saved all of the personality profiles in a table like user.(I also used the RBAC system for roles).
I have a `gridview` with 5 columns: `User job`,`Store name`,`Brand`,`Rep no`and `City-province`.
`User job`: user role
`Store name`: the store name of a user with a store role
`Brand`: brand name products
`Rep no`: representation of a user with a representative role
`City-province`: name of City and Province Representative or Store

As you can see, here is a combination of tables in a `gridview`.
My problem is to combine queries in the search using `new Query()`.

Parts of my code are as follows:

`UserSearch model`:

```
public function search($params)
{ 

    $query = Users::find();    

    if(isset($params['UserSearch']['user_job']) &&  !empty($params['UserSearch']['user_job'])) {

        $role = $params['UserSearch']['user_job'];
        $query->join('LEFT JOIN','auth_assignment','auth_assignment.user_id = temp_users.user_id')
            ->andFilterWhere(['auth_assignment.item_name' => $role, 'user_default_business' => [2, 4, 5]]);    

    } elseif(isset($params['UserSearch']['brand']) && !empty($params['UserSearch']['brand'])) {
        $brand = $params['UserSearch']['brand'];
        $query->join('LEFT JOIN', 'temp_representative',
            'temp_representative.id = temp_users.user_id')
            ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'temp_store', 'temp_store.id = temp_users.user_id')
            ->andFilterWhere(['or',
                ['like', 'temp_representative.business_id', $brand],
                ['like', 'temp_store.business_id', $brand]
            ]);
    }    

    elseif (isset($params['UserSearch']['rep_no']) && !empty($params['UserSearch']['rep_no'])){
        $code = $params['UserSearch']['rep_no'];
        $query->join('LEFT JOIN', 'temp_representative',
            'temp_representative.user_id = temp_users.user_id')
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'rep_no', $code]);
    }    

    elseif (isset($params['UserSearch']['city_province']) && !empty($params['UserSearch']['city_province'])){
        $name = $params['UserSearch']['city_province'];
        $query->join('LEFT JOIN', 'temp_store',
            'temp_store.user_id = temp_users.user_id')
            ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'temp_representative', 'temp_representative.user_id = temp_users.user_id')
            ->andFilterWhere(['or',
                ['like','store_city',$name],
                ['like','store_province',$name],
            ])
            ->orFilterWhere(['or',
                ['like','rep_city',$name],
                ['like','rep_province',$name]
            ]);

    }    
    elseif (isset($params['UserSearch']['store_name']) && !empty($params['UserSearch']['store_name'])){
        $storeName = $params['UserSearch']['store_name'];
        $query->join('LEFT JOIN', 'temp_store',
            'temp_store.user_id = temp_users.user_id')
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'store_name', $storeName]);
    } else {
        $query = Users::find()->where(['user_default_business' => [2, 4, 5]]);
    }    

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query
    ]);    

    if(!(($this->load($params)) && $this->validate())){
        return $dataProvider;
    }    

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_name_family', $this->user_name_family])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_phone', $this->user_phone]);


    return $dataProvider;    
}
```

Each field works correctly on its own but it does not work properly when combined, for example: When we enter two fields `brand` and `city-province` a while, Filtering only applies to the last field.

Without using active record relations, please advise me how to fix this problem?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following construction means that only one of matching scenarios will be executed.

```
if ($scenario1) {
    // ...
}
elseif ($scenario2) {
    // ...
}

elseif ($scenario3) {
    // ...
}
```

If you want all matching scenarios to be executed use `if` operator:

```
if ($scenario1) {
    // ...
}
if ($scenario2) {
    // ...
}

if ($scenario3) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Carelessness and carelessness ... thanks `@Bogdan`, you are right.